# Set Current date as Max Date in Calendar Widget Kony Visualiser

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am developing an application with Kony Platform. I need to use a Calendar widget wherein I need to restrict selection of future dates. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `validEndDate` properties as current date  for the calendar widget. Please find the  Same code

```
var mydate = new Date();
var currDate =[mydate.getDate(), mydate.getMonth() + 1, mydate.getFullYear()];
frmlanding.cal1.validEndDate  = currDate;
```